# Does all operators in Pytorch support back-propagation?

Tags: pytorch

I remember that in TensorFlow, there are some operators can only be used for forward operations, and no backward operations being supported/implemented for back-propagation.

My question is, are there any these kind of operators in Pytorch? If yes, could you please give some references? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have examples (for unsupported backward operations in TensorFlow) in mind?

Comment: Hi, @Ivan, thanks for your kind comment. I cannot list all those operators. But I remember that the `tf.image.non_max_suppression` operator seems no gradient back-propagation. But this depends on version, some operators might not support the gradient in one version, but after some committor submit their code, the operator might have the support after that version of TensorFlow.